# Query WP data with the WPDB API from outside WordPress

Tags: redirect, wpdb

I'm working on a project with WP, a bit like a plugin, but not quite one.

I'm encountering an issue, when trying to include a file that contains some custom SQL functions in a class, in a completely different file, I get redirected to `http://example.com/folder1/file.php/wp-admin/install.php`

Which states that I've already installed WP and I need to uninstall it before I can install it again.. But I'm not trying to install/re-install WP.

^ That sounds kinda complicated, let me give an example:

I have `file1.php` and `file2.php`. `file1.php` contains many SQL functions that I wrote to access the DB which WP uses.

And `file2.php` contains a class that includes `file1.php`, so I can use some of the SQL functions in the class.

Now, I first tested it with calling some SQL functions (`from file1.php`) in the class and came across this issue. After some debugging (removing lines, one by one), the issue was the line that includes `file1.php` (the file with all the SQL functions in it)

So for some reason, everytime I include `file1.php` in `file2.php` I get redirected to:
`http://example.com/folder1/file2.php/wp-admin/install.php`

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

**Forgot to mention something:**

`file1.php` (with all the SQL functions) does include `wp-config.php` to get the DB info, which could be related to this issue, right?

Answer (score 1):

> **Forgot to mention something:**
>
> `file1.php` (with all the SQL functions) does include `wp-config.php`
>   to get the DB info, which could be related to this issue, right?

Dollars to doughnuts, this is your problem. You should never, ever, *ever* need to load `wp-config.php` directly.

Are you trying to access WordPress functions from *outside* WordPress?

#### Edit

To access WordPress functions from *outside* the normal WordPress environment, you want to include **`wp-load.php`**, *not* `wp-config.php`.

Basic example:

```
<?php
require( 'path/to-wordpress/wp-load.php' );
?>
```

#### Edit 2

> I don't [need to access WordPress functions]. Just the DB info (host,user,password). The app I'm working on installs some extra tables in the WP db. The app will not need to touch any of WP's data. IT just uses the DB info to access its own data, in its own tables just using the same Database as the one WP uses. I would prefer to just make my own DB in the users MySQL but most users wont have permission to do so. So I have to use WP's database, but my own tables. Although the app requires WP to be installed, I don't need to access any of WP's functions ATM.

In this case, you *don't need to **load** WordPress*. You're simply accessing the database. Just omit the line entirely.

Comment: "Are you trying to access WordPress functions from outside WordPress?" if by that, you mean, file1.php and file2.php are not in the WP directory, then yes. But I'm trying to execute file2.php outside. Not in the WP GUI. How would I access the DB info then? Thanks.

Comment: I mean outside of the WordPress *environment* - i.e. external to the normally running WordPress script, which appears to be the case, based on your comment. You need to use `wp-load.php`, *not* `wp-config.php`. See updated answer.

Comment: I just tired replacing with wp-config.php with wp-load.php and the same thing is happening. When i remove the line completly, it works. So the issues does lie within including a wp-...php file but its not just the wp-config.php. wp-load.php is doing the same thing too.

Comment: Question: why do you *need* to access WordPress functions?

Comment: I don't. Just the DB info (host,user,password). The app I'm working on installs some extra tables in the WP db. The app will not need to touch any of WP's data. IT just uses the DB info to access its own data, in its own tables just using the same Database as the one WP uses. I would prefer to just make my own DB in the users MySQL but most users wont have permission to do so. So I have to use WP's database, but my own tables. Although the app requires WP to be installed, I don't need to access any of WP's functions ATM.

Comment: Then just omit the line entirely. You don't need to load WordPress at all. See updated answer.

Comment: Okay, but then how would I access the DB information. Thanks :)

Comment: You can always read the content of `wp-config.php` in, using `file()`, and then find the appropriate array strings.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you. Could you give a quick example code of how I would do that? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Try `$wp_config = file( 'path/to/wp-config.php' ); var_dump( $wp_config );` That will show you how the `wp-config.php` file gets read into the `$wp_config` varialbe, as an array - basically, each newline in the file starts a new array value.

Answer (score 1):

### The bare essentials

If you're about loading only the parts of WP that access the DB, then there's a constant there for you:

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true )
```

Simply combine that with a custom query var, so you can turn it on/off from your `wp-config.php` file:

```
if ( 
    isset( $_GET['shortinit'] )
    AND 'true' === $_GET['shortinit']
)
    define( 'SHORTINIT', true )
```

This allows you to append `?shortinit=true` to your URl to run WP without all that shine and glitter. If you need some other API functions, simply extend that wrapper in your config file and include the responsible files too.

**But** you'll have  to set the globals `$wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query` yourself. That isn't too hard if you take a look an where and how core does this.

### Routing

I also wrote about how you can add non WP rewrite rules in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72870/external-non-wp-rewrite-rules/72895#72895).