# External/non-WP rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, ajax

I have a fairly complex wordpress with multiple sub-directories:

```
example.com/sub1/
example.com/sub2/
```

I'm trying to implement some history/bookmark support, and to do that I need the URLS containing these directories to be rewritten to the directory, not the index page.  From there AJAX can take over, interpret the first URL and load the content.

I believe to do this I need to use `$wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules`

So far I have not even been able to write a simple rewrite from one directory to another:

```
//flush the rules//
function test_flush_rewrites() 
{
 global $wp_rewrite;
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
};
//add new rule//
function test_add_rewrites() 
{
 global $wp_rewrite;
 $test_new_non_wp_rules = array(
    'sub1/' => 'sub2',
 );
 $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $test_new_non_wp_rules + $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
};
//add the actions//
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'test_add_rewrites');
add_action('admin_init', 'test_flush_rewrites');
```

This results in a `404` when I navigate to the "`sub1`" directory.

also

```
'sub1'    => 'sub2' // does nothing
'/sub1/'  => 'sub2' // does nothing
'/?sub1/' => 'sub2' // does nothing
```

I believe the rule i'd like to write in `.htaccess` should look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.*$ /$1/
```

ideally i'd like to redirect `sub1/anythinghere` to `sub1`, `sub2/anythinghere` to `sub2` and so on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For future question: Please look at the WYSIWG editor buttons and format your question as well as possible. Min. take the time we need to answer to role out your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some notes.

- Install Toschos [rewrite](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite) plugin
- Install Jan Fabrys [rewrite analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin.
- Use the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)
- Add your rules to `top`.

There's also the function `add_external_rule()`, which *should* be accessible via

```
$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->add_external_rule();
```

All your external rules are accessible via `$wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules`. Here're the internals, that show you how the rules get added inside `$wp_rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules()`:

```
// add in the rules that don't redirect to WP's index.php (and thus shouldn't be handled by WP at all)
foreach ( (array) $this->non_wp_rules as $match => $query) {
    // Apache 1.3 does not support the reluctant (non-greedy) modifier.
    $match = str_replace('.+?', '.+', $match);

    // If the match is unanchored and greedy, prepend rewrite conditions
    // to avoid infinite redirects and eclipsing of real files.
    //if ($match == '(.+)/?$' || $match == '([^/]+)/?$' ) {
        //nada.
    //}

    $rules .= 'RewriteRule ^' . $match . ' ' . $home_root . $query . " [QSA,L]\n";
}
```

The phpDocBlock for that method states the following

> Retrieve `mod_rewrite` formatted rewrite rules to write to `.htaccess.`
>
> Does not actually write to the `.htaccess` file, but creates the rules for the process that will.
>
> Will add the non_wp_rules property rules to the `.htaccess` file before the WordPress rewrite rules one.

Comment: I'm confused, as I started with the Rewrite API, then moved to $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules.  You tell me to use the API, then add_external_rule?  I'm thinking $wp_rewrite is still the way to go.  Not finding much on the add_external_rule, but i'll mess around with it, thanks

Comment: $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'sub1/$', 'sub2' );  still results in a 404

Comment: I've now added $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( '([^/]+)/.*$', '/$1/' );  which results in a 404 on the client side, and a 500 internal server error on the admin side (obviously).  The problem now is I have no idea how to refresh my rules, to start testing again.

Comment: I'm back in by modifying the .htaccess file and uploading it

Comment: Use `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules()` in code to flush them (shouldn't be used on each request - only for dev/testing). Have you installed the plugins I mentioned? Btw: Please go and update your question with new information instead of adding a comment flood here. Thanks.

Comment: $wp_rewrite->flush_rules() wouldn't have worked as my pages weren't even being loaded by apache.  But I fixed the problem with .htaccess   I'm thinking now there is no problem with the rules i have been writing, i just need to better understandhow  wordpress interprates URLS

Comment: That's why I linked you the two plugins. The MonkeyManRewriteAnalyzer has that name for a reason...